# Are $f(x)=\cot x \tan x$ and $g(x)=1$ equal to each other?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, functions

We have two functions  $f(x)=\cot x \tan x$ and $g(x)=1$. Are these function equal to each other?

For the function $f(x)$ I know for $x\neq\frac{k\pi}{2}$ it is equal to $1$ but for  $x=\frac{k\pi}{2}$ We have $\infty\times0$ and I think it is undefined. So the functions aren't equal to each other. Am I right?

Comment: $f(x)=g(x)$ when $f(x)$ is defined

Comment: The answer depends on the domain that each function is defined on. There is no implicit assumption that a function *must* be defined on the maximal domain where the expression "makes sense".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The functions aren't equal to each other because $f(x)$ has a removable discontinuity at $x=\frac{k\pi}{2}$, but $g(x)$ does not.
Basically $f$ and $g$ have different domain, hence they cannot be equal.

Comment: "*f and g have different domain*" That's an assumption, even a reasonable one, but the question does not specify the domain. Suppose for example that $f$ and $g$ are both defined as functions $\mathbb Z \to \mathbb R$, then $f = g$.

Comment: True, if g(x) has been defined such that it exists only at the points where f exists too, they would be equal. So it does depend upon domain of definition. It is best we ask @Soheil to provide the domain for which the two functions have been defined. But the way the asker has shown us his attempt makes it likely that g is defined over all real numbers

Comment: @Ritam_Dasgupta It is a high school type of problem (many of them aren't posed rigorously) . So I think your answer is reasonable.

Comment: Hmm I think so too.